# Can't set filesystem to rw after crash

Tags: filesystems, crash, readonly, read-write

My Mint crashed twice yesterday. Googling for frozen system with flashing caps and scroll-lock LEDs made me believe it was a hardware problem. I carefully cleaned everything, and the hardware seems to work ok again - I had no more crashes.
Today I tried downloading a file and I got a pop-up saying the disk is write-protected. Also, `apt-get update` returns me a lot of errors about "read-only filesystem".
I tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/285253/247495) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74091/247495). Here are the outputs:

`# blockdev -v --setrw /dev/sdb
set read-write succeeded.`

`# mount / -o remount,rw
mount: cannot remount /dev/sdb6 read-write, is write-protected`

`# hdparm -r 0 /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)`

`# mount / -o remount,rw
mount: cannot remount /dev/sdb6 read-write, is write-protected`

I tried both `blockdev` and `hdparm` using `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdb6`, and running `# echo $?` after each of them always returns `0`, indicating success, but nothing seems to work.

Also, my `/home` folder is at `/dev/sdb7` and I can write files normally to it.

Here is the output for `# fdisk -l`
`Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors`
`Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes`
`Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`
`I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes`
`Disklabel type: dos`
`Disk identifier: 0x0005683d`

`Device     Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type`
`/dev/sdb1  *    976963584 1953523711 976560128 465,7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`
`/dev/sdb2            2046  976962885 976960840 465,9G  5 Extended`
`/dev/sdb5            2048    2000895   1998848   976M 82 Linux swap / Solaris`
`/dev/sdb6         2002944   41062399  39059456  18,6G 83 Linux`
`/dev/sdb7        41064448  976962885 935898438 446,3G 83 Linux`

The `/dev/sdb1` is a NTFS partition I made to be accessible from Windows, which is at `/dev/sda`.

Any ideas on how I could fix this? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Backup it and buy a new disk.