# Fix read only file system usb

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, flash-memory

I have a usb flash memory which I can't do anything on it because its read only:

```
sudo fdisk -l

Device     Boot   Start     End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048    7864319 7862272  3.8G  b W95 FAT32
```

I've tried to fix file system with `mkfs` and I got this :

```
sudo mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sdc1

mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
mkfs.fat: unable to open /dev/sdc1: Read-only file system
```

How can I fix this?

PS: Let's assume the USB is not write-protected by design, such as with a manual switch.

Comment: The command `mount` (probably as root) is the one to use to change mounted filesystem state, not `mkfs`.

Comment: Is this a sandisk usb? Some have a hardware 'safety lock' that locks the usb to read-only in the event of a usb power fluctuation. I had one that did this and had to be returned, though they replaced it FOC.

Comment: Is it plugged into a USB 3.0 socket (the blue kind)?  I have a 4 GB flash drive that mounts as read-only when connected to USB 3.0, but I can write to it when I use the older USB sockets on the same computer (running Xubuntu 16.04).

Comment: we have same distro but unfortunately my laptop does not have any USB 2.0 socket.I will try it on another laptop
.Thanks

Comment: That wasn't the problem...
I tried  all the things I knew on USB 2.0 port and it was the same result

Comment: Have you read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74090/linux-how-to-change-hdd-state-from-readonly-after-temporarly-crash  is proposes `blockdev --setrw` or `hdparm -r 0`

Comment: Try according to the following link, [Postrequisites - restore the USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Postrequisites_-_restore_the_USB_stick)

Comment: @sudodus
I'm afraid I don't have access to the flash memory anymore.

Comment: You can analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, solve it with help from this link, [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: I recommend this is flagged as a "duplicate" instead of "off-topic" and go with @Sandburg 's comment...

Comment: @PJBrunet The originating user [doesn't have access to the hardware any longer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411647/fix-read-only-file-system-usb#comment866097_411647), and can therefore not verify that a solution works or not. The question was closed as "non-reproducable, problem went away by itself".

Comment: Gaultheria nailed it, was stuck in usb 3 socket, as soon as i put into a usb 2, I could work with the files again. Strange behavior, glad I came across his comment

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you are performing filesystem management actions with escalated privileges. Most systems do not let users modify filesystems.
2. Ensure the device isn't already mounted. As root, execute `lsblk` and look for any filesystems using `/dev/sdc1`. If it is mounted you will have to unmount prior to formatting with mkfs.
3. Make sure the device is not a read-only UFD. Though uncommon, these do exist ... usually as hand-outs from vendor booths with product sheets or other vendor info on them.

### Quick walkthrough of steps

1. Verify you are performing all tasks as root. Best way is to simply open a  shell as root: In a terminal, execute `sudo -i` is usually the easiest way.
2. Unmount the device with `umount /dev/sdc1` (may give error info if it is not mounted, no worries if this happens)

VVV **WARNING THIS WILL DESTROY ALL DATA ON THE DEVICE** VVV

3. Format the device `mkfs.vfat /dev/sdc1` (you can force 32bit size if you wish, but mkfs will select whatever fits best for the size of the volume)

If this does not work, you may want to wipe the device, recreate the partition with fdisk, and try again:

`wipefs -a /dev/sdc`

Again, this will destroy any remaining data. You have been warned.

Comment: I unmount it before I use these commands.

Comment: wipefs also invokes error read only file system

Comment: `mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/mmcblk0: Read-only file system`

still the same error

Comment: How does this help one get write access to the filesystem? I mean sure, I can overwrite it, no problem. But there is a deep mystery as to why this DOS image I wrote to it only mounts readonly.

Comment: This worked for me: I used the pendrive to create boottable linux installer

Comment: See Gaultheria's comment abovel before you set off on any complicated route, just try to make sure it's not a usb 3 vs usb 2 issue, changing to a usb 2 port fixed the read only issue immediately for me. I'd add that as  an answer because rule 1 is always try the simple thing before anything else, exclude that, than go to the complex stuff but this is closed.

Comment: Didn't work for me. The big problem, no matter what I do, I still see "read-only" warning.