# How to fix read-only EFI system partition?

Tags: grub, uefi, readonly

I have a EFI partition, /dev/sda1, that I was once able to install GRUB to and change the boot order with efibootmgr without issue, unfortunately now, however, I cannot I receive 'Read-only file system' errors from grub-install (specifically, when mounted to /boot/efi, `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi /dev/sda` and efibootmgr. I have tried wiping it with:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1
```

but I still get this error. Specifically `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi /dev/sda` gives:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Could not delete variable: Read-only file system
efibootmgr: ** Warning ** : Boot0002 has same label gentoo
Could not prepare Boot variable: Read-only file system
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

I saw [Fix read only file system usb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411647/fix-read-only-file-system-usb), but I can't wipe this disk with `wipefs` I have several distros installed and set up and it'd take a while to recover from such a wipe. Oddly grub-install does still add files to /dev/sda1, it's just the boot order that cannot seem to be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the error message is "**Could not delete variable:** Read-only file system". It is actually trying to manipulate the UEFI boot variables, and failing there.

The errors are actually referring to `efivarfs` filesystem that is used to access the UEFI boot variables, which should normally be mounted at `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`. There may also be an older version of the UEFI variable access mechanism, located at `/sys/firmware/efi/vars`.

If you have missed the CONFIG_EFIVAR_FS kernel configuration option, the driver for this virtual filesystem may not exist in your kernel (if compiled as a module, it is named `efivarfs`). If the driver is available, make sure this filesystem is listed in `/etc/fstab`: if your system's boot scripts don't handle it specially, you may need a line like this in your /etc/fstab file:

```
efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars efivarfs defaults 0 0
```

Update: apparently the initial implementation of `efivarfs` could cause some computers to be bricked if someone ran `rm -rf /sys/firmware/efi/efivarfs`.

Protection against that was added in new kernels by having all but the known-safe variable items in `efivarfs` be immutable (similar to `chattr +i`) by default, and having legitimate UEFI variable manipulation tools like `efibootmgr` change the file attributes before making modifications.

In a rolling-release system, it is possible to have the kernel update that makes the `efivarfs` change land on your system before the userspace tools like `grub-install` have received the necessary modification to deal with it. This might have happened in this case.