# Unable to open device '/dev/sdb' for writing! Errno is 30! Aborting write!

Tags: usb-drive, usb-device, gdisk

#### 1st set of commands

Using these commands with GDISK:

```
> sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
o
n
w
```

I get:

> Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE
> EXISTING PARTITIONS!!
>
> Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): Y
>
> OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdb.
>
> Unable to open device '/dev/sdb' for writing! Errno is 30! Aborting write!

#### 2nd set of commands

Also using another set of GDISK commands:

```
> sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
x
z
```

I get:

> About to wipe out GPT on /dev/sdb. Proceed? (Y/N): Y
>
> Problem opening '/dev/sdb' for writing! Program will now terminate.
>
> Blank out MBR? (Y/N): Y
>
> Warning! MBR not overwritten! Error is 30!

#### Why

The device is a flash USB drive.

- What might be the cause?
- What else can I try?

#### DD

The `dd` couldn't help:

```
> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb status=progress
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': Read-only file system
```

#### FDISK

FDISK didn't help too:

```
> sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Read-only file system
```

#### HDPARM

I had already used `hdparm`:

```
> sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
```

#### macOS

I'm able to see USB drive content by a MacBook! So, the hardware is fine. macOS reports the filesystem as MS-DOS (FAT32).

#### macOS Disk Utility

Trying to format the device with macOS Disk Utility throws these error:

When erasing partition:

> Starting secure erase…
>
> Unmounting disk
>
> Creating the partition map
>
> Couldn’t open device.
>
> Operation failed…

When erasing filesystem:

> Unmounting disk
>
> Couldn’t modify partition map.
>
> Operation failed…

#### Wipefs tool

Wipefs tool output:

```
> sudo wipefs -a /dev/sdb
wipefs: error: /dev/sdb: probing initialization failed: Read-only file system
```

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the kernel messages? Have you tried a different command, such as `parted` or `fdisk`? I don't know if there is anything on the drive you want to keep, but if not, try writing to it with another tool like `dd`.

Comment: @berndbausch Thanks =) Updated the post :)

Comment: Disks cannot be mounted while you alter partitions on the disk.  Read `man umount`.

Comment: Something makes the drive readonly. See https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only and other articles in Stackexchange and the internet. You could try it on a different computer, e.g. one running Windows. Or simply buy another drive.

Comment: Please try `sudo touch /dev/wibble` (or any other filename in `/dev` that _does not_ exist). If you get a `Read-only file system` error the problem is nothing to do with `/dev/sdb` but rather something's gone wrong with the `/dev` subsystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device make and model is

```
SanDisk Ultra Media USB External Physical Disk
```

According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411647/fix-read-only-file-system-usb#comment737857_411647):

> Is this a sandisk usb? Some have a hardware 'safety lock' that locks the usb to read-only in the event of a usb power fluctuation. I had one that did this and had to be returned, though they replaced it FOC.

According to [that](https://superuser.com/a/777214/571029):

> According to [SanDisk customer
> service](http://forums.sandisk.com/t5/All-SanDisk-USB-Flash-Drives/SanDisk-Cruzer-Blade-16GB-write-protected-error/td-p/253484/page/7),
> those drives have a safety mechanism that disables writes when error
> conditions are detected, to protect the data:
>
> > The flash drive has detected a potential fault and has become write protected to prevent data loss. There is no method to fix this. You
> > will need to backup your data and replace the flash drive.